# ruby class seems to be stuck in the past in a rails app even after restarting rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've changed my if/then blocks and still I see a historical mistake in the exception log. It seems like the rails interpreter is stuck in the past... I restarted the server several times.

> C:/Sites/chartstoke/app/src/file_processor_service.rb:15: syntax
>   error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' (if ctr >
>   11) do ^ C:/Sites/chartstoke/app/src/file_processor_service.rb:17:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting ')' else ^
>   C:/Sites/chartstoke/app/src/file_processor_service.rb:19: syntax
>   error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' end ^
>   C:/Sites/chartstoke/app/src/file_processor_service.rb:63: syntax
>   error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' end ^

In my application.rb file I have autoload on:

```
config.autoload_paths += %w(#{config.root}/services #{config.root}/src)
```

Here is my controller:

```
class FileProcessorController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def upload
    end

    def import
        file_processor = FileProcessorService.new
        @file_sample = file_processor.present_data_sample(params[:file].path)
        if (@file_sample) then
            render 'index'
        end
    end
end
```

And here is my Ruby file_processor_service.rb class:

```
class FileProcessorService

    require 'csv'
    require 'elasticsearch'

    def initialize
    end

    # This method will just parse the first 10 - 15 rows for user to see data sample.
    def present_data_sample(file_path)
        @filesample = {}
        ctr=0
        uploaded_file_path = file_path
        CSV.foreach(uploaded_file_path, headers: true) do |row|
            while ctr <= 11 do
                @filesample << row.to_hash
                ctr += 1
                if ctr > 11 then
                    return @filesample
                else
                    return @filesample
                end
            end
        end
    end


    def load_index(file)
        uploaded_file_path = params[:file].path
        index_name = File.basename(uploaded_file_path, ".*")
        ctr=1
        CSV.foreach(uploaded_file_path, headers: true) do |row|
            @es_client.index(index: index_name,
                type:  index_name+"_type",
                id: index_name+"."+ctr,
                body: row.to_hash
                )
            ctr +=1
        end
    end


        # def build_indexing_body(key, value)

        # end


        # private 

        # def establish_client_node(server)
        #   @es_client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(hosts: ['#{server}:9200'], reload_connections: true)

        # end
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I see a historical mistake in the exception log`? Do you actually get this error when running an app?

Comment: I thought I was missing an `end` keyword and a `then` for my if. THats all resolved. But I'm still seeing the same error. I don't think there is anything wrong with my syntax though... Why am I getting that error above?

Comment: Are you sure you are pasting the updated file? Can you try again without the additional `end` at the end?

Comment: `if` does not require `then` - it's optional. Are you sure you saved the file?

Comment: You have the same return after "ctr > 11 then" so there is unnecessary code. Also, you never reset ctr so you'll never get results @filesample after the first row.

Comment: unrelated, but present_data_sample isn't going to work as documented - the return statements are going to return from the function the first time through,  not after 10 loops

Comment: Also, are you sure you are checking page via localhost? Error is still displaying the old code. Also, could you please paste this code to codereview stack exchange - it could use some refactoring.

Comment: The real problem seems to be in the controller. It still highlights this line: `file_processor = FileProcessorService.new`. I've stubbed out everything in FileProcessorService and still no cigar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your present_data_sample method needs to be rewritten. You should not be returning inside of a block because you'll exit the block. This may fix your error depending on the rest of your code:

```
def present_data_sample(file_path)
    @filesample = {}
    ctr=0
    uploaded_file_path = file_path
    CSV.foreach(uploaded_file_path, headers: true) do |row|
       ctr += 1
       break if ctr > 11
       @filesample << row.to_hash   
    end

    return @filesample
end
```

Comment: Alright. Regardless of the refactoring. I put a hello world method in my FileProcessorService. Even that gives the same exact error. the problem looks to be in the instantiation of the FileProcessorService class in my controller. `file_processor = FileProcessorService.new`.. Rails is throwing that same error! I stubbed out everything in that class except for the helloworld method... And still no cigar!!

Comment: figured it out. Really stupid setup on my end. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change

```
while ctr <= 11 do
  @filesample << row.to_hash
  ctr += 1
  if ctr > 11 then
    return @filesample
  else
    return @filesample
  end
end
```

to:

```
while ctr < 11
  @filesample << row.to_hash
  ctr += 1
  return @filesample if ctr == 11
end
```

Comment: could you explain why?

Comment: `then` is not required for an `if` block in ruby and same as you don't require an explicit `do`, and you want to return only if you have looped 10 times, I guess so the else is not required at all

Comment: Alright. Regardless of the refactoring. I put a hello world method in my FileProcessorService. Even that gives the same exact error. the problem looks to be in the instantiation of the FileProcessorService class in my controller. `file_processor = FileProcessorService.new`.. Rails is throwing that same error! I stubbed out everything in that class except for the helloworld method... And still no cigar!!